# Перевод из одной раскладки в другую

Tags: ruby

Нужно перевести текст из одной раскладки в другую. То есть из `куищще` получить `reboot`, а из `lf` получить `да`. Есть ли готовое решение на `Ruby/Ruby on Rails`?

Или лучше самому написать метод аля

```
def self.change_lng_mode(str)
    keymap = {a: "Ф", b: "и"  ... }
    str.gsub!(/[A-z]/) do |char|
        keymap[char.to_sym]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во фреймворке для верстания сайтиков этой ф-ции, конечно, не место.
Она есть в самом языке -- [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr)

```
def self.change_lng_mode(str)
  str.tr 'qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?\'',
         'йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджячсмитьбю.ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪ/ФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,э'
end
```

Comment: Я думал, что, возможно, в I18n есть нечто подобное.

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел ничего стандартного. Расширил класс `String`

```
class String
  def change_lng_mode
    keymap = $arrReplace = {'q' => 'й',
                             'w' => 'ц',
                             'e' => 'у',
                             'r' => 'к',
                             't' => 'е',
                             'y' => 'н',
                             'u' => 'г',
                             'i' => 'ш',
                             'o' => 'щ',
                             'p' => 'з',
                             '[' => 'х',
                             ']' => 'ъ',
                             'a' => 'ф',
                             's' => 'ы',
                             'd' => 'в',
                             'f' => 'а',
                             'g' => 'п',
                             'h' => 'р',
                             'j' => 'о',
                             'k' => 'л',
                             'l' => 'д',
                             ';' => 'ж',
                             "'" => 'э',
                             'z' => 'я',
                             'x' => 'ч',
                             'c' => 'с',
                             'v' => 'м',
                             'b' => 'и',
                             'n' => 'т',
                             'm' => 'ь',
                             ',' => 'б',
                             '.' => 'ю',
                             '/' => '.',
                             '`' => 'ё',
                             'Q' => 'Й',
                             'W' => 'Ц',
                             'E' => 'У',
                             'R' => 'К',
                             'T' => 'Е',
                             'Y' => 'Н',
                             'U' => 'Г',
                             'I' => 'Ш',
                             'O' => 'Щ',
                             'P' => 'З',
                             '{' => 'Х',
                             '}' => 'Ъ',
                             'A' => 'Ф',
                             'S' => 'Ы',
                             'D' => 'В',
                             'F' => 'А',
                             'G' => 'П',
                             'H' => 'Р',
                             'J' => 'О',
                             'K' => 'Л',
                             'L' => 'Д',
                             ':' => 'Ж',
                             '"' => 'Э',
                             '|' => '/',
                             'Z' => 'Я',
                             'X' => 'Ч',
                             'C' => 'С',
                             'V' => 'М',
                             'B' => 'И',
                             'N' => 'Т',
                             'M' => 'Ь',
                             '<' => 'Б',
                             '>' => 'Ю',
                             '?' => ',',
                             '~' => 'Ё',
                             '@' => '"',
                             '#' => '№',
                             '$' => ';',
                             '^' => ':',
                             '&' => '?'}
    self.gsub(/[A-z]/, keymap)
  end
end
```